# Timer: canceling running task

Tags: java, timer, tomcat7, scheduled-tasks

I need to create async thread that runs once with a delay of 2 minutes and that can be killed at any moment. I saw several possible solutions:

1. `ScheduledExecutorService` and `FutureTask` allow me to interrupt a running task, but I will have to invoke `shutdown()` to terminate all the running threads, and this will block user until the processes were terminated. Also, I will have to frequently invoke `Thread.interrupted()` as described in [Enno Shioji's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903342/why-thread-started-by-scheduledexecutorservice-schedule-never-quits).
2. `Timer` and `TimerTask` do not require to release running threads, but I have no way to interrupt a running timer thread (`Timer.cancel()` just cancels future scheduling)
3. Using [Thread and sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453295/timer-timertask-versus-thread-sleep-in-java) with [thread interruption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) problem.

Is there a good solution? (I'm using tomcat 7)

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests and researches, FutureTask.cancel() and Threads need similar handling of interrupts, as stated in [Enno Shioji's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903342/why-thread-started-by-scheduledexecutorservice-schedule-never-quits)

> 1. Check interruption flag in your logic
> 2. Act upon Interrupted exception

An example that tests interruption flag:

```
private final class MyTask implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try{
            for(int j=0; j<100000000; j++) {
                for(int i=1; i<1000000000; i++){
                    if(Thread.interrupted()){ //Don't use Thread.interrupt()!
                        Log.debug("Thread was interrupted for" + cache);
                        return; //Stop doing what you are doing and terminate.
                    }
                    Math.asin(0.1565365897770/i);
                    Math.tan(0.4567894289/i);
                }
            }                            
        }catch(Throwable e){//if exception is uncaught, the scheduler may not run again 
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand, `ScheduledExecutorService` maybe be `shutdown` when application ends running

Answer (score 1):

For your scenario 2 with TimerTask, why not just return from the run() method after calling this.cancel()?

Here's a snippet from something I wrote.  I use the same technique whenever the tool encounters a situation that would make further execution invalid, like a misconfiguration.

```
...
if ( count < 1 ) {
   logger.error("CANCELING THREAD FOR " + host + ":" + jmxPort + "! " +
                "- CONFIGURATION INCOMPLETE - DUMP_COUNT must be 1 or greater.");
   this.cancel();
   return;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Option 1 you can use [FutureTask.cancel()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) with `mayInterruptIfRunning` parameter set to `true` to cancel your tasks.

The [ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) creates a [ScheduledFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html), which still can be canceled trough the FutureTask api.

Here is a naive test I've used to verify that task gets canceled. I suppose the worker thread may not be interrupted if you do some blocking IO (network or disk), but I haven't tested it. If cancel is called while task is not running, it all stops nicely, but if task is running when cancel is called the executor will try to kill the thread.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);

    ScheduledFuture<?> future = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        int i = 0;
        public void run() {
            int j = i++;
            System.err.println("Run " + j);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("Interrupted " + j);
            }
        }

    }, 1000L, 2000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    Thread.sleep(10000L);
    System.err.println("Canceled " + future.cancel(true));

    Thread.sleep(20000L);

    executor.shutdownNow();
    System.err.println("Finished");
}
```

Comment: right, but there are 2 drawbacks. First, if I start a long process in thread, I have to refer the isInterrupted flag constantly; second, I must invoke shutdown to release running threads, and this will block user until thread finished running

Comment: The FutureTask returned by ExecutorService abstracts you from working with Threads. As per JavaDoc, it will take care of interrupting worker thread if you pass true for mayInterruptIfRunning.

Comment: Not exactly according to Enno Shioji's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903342/why-thread-started-by-scheduledexecutorservice-schedule-never-quits

Comment: I updated my answer with additional references to ScheduledFuture javaDoc that explicitly says that scheduled task can be canceled.

Comment: thanks, I will test it. But still, this approach requires me to invoke  ScheduledExecutorService.shutdown() in the end to release threads. I do not want to block user and wait until all the threads finished running

Comment: Not sure that "end" you're referring to. Cancel happens on ScheduledFuture instance, that will deal with a worker thread for this particular task. If there is something else scheduled you don't chancel trough ScheduledFuture, those supposedly shut down at the application shutdown...

Comment: If I dont invoke ScheduledExecutorService.shutdown, thread that was not canceled may be reused next time? Or it will remain in memory?

Comment: Regarding the cancellation issue: I built a test with task.cancel(true) and I see that the task is not canceled, even though cancel() return true

Comment: You'll have to post your test. I did my own experiments and it is working as I expected. See above.

Comment: Your test works because you invoke Thread.sleep. Future.cancel() fires interrupt, and sleep knows to be interrupted by InterruptionException. If instead of sleep you build a long loop inside another loop, it will not be interrupted by default. I'll add an example to my post

Comment: Naturally it won't terminate. However when that long loop finishes task execution will stop.

Comment: But if I need to stop it in the middle of the loop, I need to add logic to the thread loop

Comment: I should point out that your original question don't have anything about long running or blocking tasks. Don't know your specifics, but if your periodical task runs too long, maybe you need to consider changing it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9485/discussion-between-lili-and-eugene-kuleshov)